# Creating New Sub-Class Instances

Tags: java, subclass

I am new to Java and as an exercise creating a game of Battleship.  There are, obviously, two game boards (one for each player) and each board will have three ships assigned to it.  My idea, then, is to make a "GameBoard" class with a "ship" class within it, so I can create new ships which are instances of the boards they will be placed upon.  Here's what I have so far:

```
public class GameBoard {
    int columnCount = 7;
    int rowCount = 7;
    int spaceCount = rowCount*columnCount;

    private class ship {
        private String name;
        private void setName(String newName) {
            name = newName;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is how to call a new ship within a gameboard.  To create a new board I would do this:

```
GameBoard player1 = new Gameboard();
```

Where do I go from there, though?  Would it be something like this?

```
player1.ship ship1 = new player1.ship();
```

My gut is telling me that is very wrong, and I'm just not sure what to do.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this.

```
public class GameBoard {
int columnCount = 7;
int rowCount = 7;
int spaceCount = rowCount*columnCount;
ship s;

}


public class ship {
    private String name;
    private void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

and then

```
GameBoard gb = new GameBoard();
gb.s = new ship();
```

Comment: Perfect.  Now my question is how can I have an unlimited number of potential ships being added?  Right now, I have to pre-define the slots where I will be adding ships (s) but what if I have no idea how many I'll want and want to be able to add them willy-nilly?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: keep an array or list of ship in your gameboard class and you can add as many as ship you want to  : keep List<ship> s; inside the gameboard definition and add new ship as  gb.s = new List<ship>(); gb.s.add(new ship());

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you so much for all your help.  If you don't mind, why do I have to declare a new list after I've already defined it as a list in the GameBoard class?

Comment: List<ship> s; in this line you are declaring the list but this list is not initialized until you write new List<ship>();   it is only initialization of the list and then you can add as many objects you want to the list

Comment: And is there any more convenient way to manipulate it other than .get(index)?  Thanks again by the way, you've certainly gone well out of your way to help me!

Comment: no , not actually. either you use any data structure , you have to call get(index) to get specific ship. you can use HashMap<key, Object> structure for storing ships to make your object access faster

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to instantiate a new ship from within the outer class? In that case you can simply write

```
ship t = new ship();
```

Comment: That's a start, but how do I associate it with the "player1" GameBoard?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instance a ship from outer class, you should:

1. Make ship class static.
2. Make ship class public.

As the following:

```
public class GameBoard {
    int columnCount = 7;
    int rowCount = 7;
    int spaceCount = rowCount*columnCount;

    public static class ship {
        private String name;
        private void setName(String newName) {
            name = newName;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
 ship1 = new GameBoard.ship();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ship is a private class so it can only be modified by GameBoard. You can create a ship in these ways:

```
public class GameBoard {
int columnCount = 7;
int rowCount = 7;
int spaceCount = rowCount*columnCount;
ship _ship = new ship();

private class ship {
    private String name;
    private void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
}
public ship getShip(){return _ship);
```

In which you would have to set the name via `player.getShip().setName("USS SOMETHING")`

Or better yet

```
public class GameBoard {
    int columnCount = 7;
    int rowCount = 7;
    int spaceCount = rowCount*columnCount;
    ship _ship;

    public GameBoard(String shipName){
       _ship = new ship();
       _ship.setName(shipName);
    }

    private class ship {
        private String name;
        private void setName(String newName) {
            name = newName;
        }
    }
```

In which you would set the ships name when you create the GameBoard. `GameBoard player1 = new GameBoard("USS SOMETHING")`